# typescript d.ts file import rxjs type definitions only

Tags: typescript

I'm using `.d.ts` files to declare `interfaces` so that i don't need to explicitly import them in other files

my `tsconfing.json` is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "tslint-language-service"
      },
      {
        "name": "@angular/language-service"
      }
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "bootstrap",
      "jquery",
      "typeahead"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2016",
      "es2017"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/main.aot.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

my example `.d.ts` is

```
interface SomeData{
    field:string;
}
```

but I want add a `Observable` field in this like

```
interface SomeData{
    field:string;
    field2:Observable<string>;
}
```

for this I'm trying to import type definition for `Observable`

adding type definition by `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Obsevable'` breaks no import functionality

and adding type definition using `/// <reference >` is not working
the things I tried are

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts" />
```

Also there is no `@types` package for `rxjs5`

Any suggestions?

Edit: Also tried

```
/// <reference types="rxjs/Observable" />
```

Comment: What do you mean with "breaks no import functionality"?

Comment: Create a .d.ts file in some folder and define some interface only. Now you can refer that interface in all other .TS files without importing it.put some import statement in .d.ts file.now you have to explicitly import that interface in other files

Comment: You just have to wrap your interface in `declare global { }` then